# How to use array_walk on class method that does not fit the $callback parameter order

Tags: php

i have a two dimensional array e.g

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [person_id] => 55487
            [score] => 1.30427
            [mistakes] => 103.874811
            [description] => first record
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [person_id] => 55487
            [score] => 1.30427
            [mistakes] => 103.874811
            [description] => second record
        )

)
```

then I have a class function called

```
public function saveData($dbConnection, $param) {
    // function definition here
}
```

now how to use the array_walk with this function ?

I tried

```
array_walk($myArray,[$this,'saveData'],$dbConnection,$param);
```

I tried

```
array_walk($myArray,[$this,'saveData'],[$dbConnection,$param]);
```

none of these work..how to do it ?

Comment: I think you should use `array_walk_recursive` here.

Comment: your suggestion does not work

Comment: You can pass $userdata to array_walk as third parameter - but it will also be passed as _third_ parameter to your callback function, the first two are always the current item, and its index. If you want to call a method that has a totally different parameter signature - then you will have to wrap the call of that into an anonymous function/closure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to documentation of [array_walk](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php):

[image: phpdocs]

Especially this line:

> If the optional **userdata** parameter is supplied, it will be passed as the third parameter to the callback.

The extra parameter `$userdata` has to be at the 3rd parameter of your `$callback`. There is no way to workround the parameter order in `array_walk()`. But your method is clear using `$dbConnection` as the 1st parameter in your `saveData()` method.

There are 2 sensible ways to solve this:

1. Change your class method. Either to store the database connection in your class instance to remove it entirely from the parameter needs:

   ```php
   public function saveData($param) {
       $dbConnection = $this->$dbConnection; // has to set this attr. somewhere else.
       // function definition here
   }

   // ...

   // call it like this:
   array_walk($myArray, [$this,'saveData']);
   ```

   or change the parameter order accord to the `$callback` requirement

   ```php
   public function saveData($param, $key, $dbConnection) {
       // function definition here
   }

   // ...

   // call it like this:
   array_walk($myArray, [$this,'saveData'], $dbConnection);
   ```
2. Keep the method. Use an intermediate callback function instead:

   ```php
   // call it like this in your method:
   array_walk($myArray, function ($param, $key, $dbConnection) {
     return $this->saveData($dbConnection, $param);
   }, $dbConnection);
   ```